# readLines error while iterating lots of files

Tags: r, readlines

I need to iterate through some files (a lot actually) and fix some issues via gsub.

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
lapply(list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE), function(file){
    tryCatch(a1 <- xml2::read_xml(file),
             error = function(e){
               fix_to_write <- readLines(file) %>%
                 gsub("&", "and", .)
               writeLines(fix_to_write, file)
             })
  })
```

The problem is after a while i get the error that it cant open my a file: :

> In readLines(file_to_open) :
>     kann Datei '/Volumes/data/welt/xml_out/2012-02/13858485.xml' nicht öffnen: Too many open files
>   Ausführung angehalten
>   rm: /var/folders/39/z521yg593sx8_thrj843qj_r0000gn/T//Rtmpw4AKJr: Too many open files

I tried to various solutions like "closeAllConnections()" or "close(file)". Nothing worked. Any suggestions? I work on Mac...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as I've never run into that problem myself, but I assume this should work:

```
lapply(list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE), function(file){
  tryCatch(a1 <- xml2::read_xml(file),
           error = function(e){
             con <- file(description = file)
             fix_to_write <- readLines(file) %>%
               gsub("&", "and", .)
             close(con)
             writeLines(fix_to_write, file)
           })
})
```

`readLines` will actually open a connection to the file if provided a character string. This should be closed on exit but maybe it makes more sense to do it explicitly. Let me know if this helps.